# Selenium Grid: always show the same session for multiple concurrent sessions

Tags: docker, selenium-grid

Selenium Grid: always show the same session for multiple concurrent sessions.

```
  http://localhost:4444/ui#/sessions


   session1
   session2
   session3
   session4
   session5
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: 3
services:
  selenium:
    image: selenium/standalone-chrome:112.0-chromedriver-112.0-grid-4.9.0-20230421
    ports:
      - "4444:4444"
```

When clicking session1/2/3/4, always show the running session5.

Answer (score 0):

Check at the bottom of the vnc window - are there multiple windows of your browser open? You should see a window open for each session you've triggered, though the last one to open always seems to be the one that displays.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).